# C++ code does not work on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu

I have this code that runs without any errors in visual studio but doesn't on Ubuntu i compile it via terminal(`g++ try.cpp -o try`). May be you can find out why?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int ***lol(int *a, int n, int m)
{
    int ***trtr = (int ***)new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        trtr[i] = (int **)new int[m];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            trtr[i][j] = &a[i * m + j];
        }
    }
    // for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    // {
    //         for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    //         {
    //                 *trtr[i][j] = a[i * m + j];
    //         }
    // }
    return trtr;
}
int main()
{
    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;
    int *a = new int[n * m];
    for (int i = 0; i < n * m; i++)
        a[i] = i;
    int ***kekl = lol(a, n, m);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            cout << *kekl[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Input example: 10 10

```
Output: 36495648 36495688 36495728 36495768 0 36495772 0 36495784 0 36495788 
0 36495784 0 36495788 0 36495792 0 36495804 0 23 
0 36495804 0 23 24 25 30 31 32 33 
30 31 32 33 34 35 40 41 42 43 
40 41 42 43 44 45 50 51 52 53 
50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

If you will include commented section u will receive just Segmentation fault (core dumped)

One more time on Windows in Visual Studio it works fine.

Comment: Please learn how to make a reasonable title for your questions (and tags).

Comment: Why are you casting the result of `new int[]` (to the wrong type, at that)?

Comment: initially i used (int***)malloc() and (int**)malloc() but i had the same issue then i changed it to this

Comment: *Why* is this even a triple pointer? There is not reason for the third level of indirection at all. Also if you would just use `std::vector` things would become much easier to read (and remove all the memory leaks you have in this code)

Comment: That's because that code is wrong. Why cast? Why not just do it the right way?

Comment: well this is just a piece of code. I use shared memory and i don't know how to assign it to the 2d vector so i used 1d array an then created 2d array that i assigned to that array and i need triple pointer in order to have same memory addresses so i can change shared memory without any index magic. P.S(sorry for grammar and all that :))

Comment: You should compile with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g try.cpp -o try`, then improve the code to get no warnings, then  **[use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code has some problems, so I can only guess what you wanted to achieve.

The most problematic thing here is `int ***trtr = (int ***)new int[n];`.

I guess you want to allocate a two-dimensional int array here. So you need to allocate space for n pointers to int arrays.
What you do instead is to allocate an int array of size n, which you cast to a `int***`. The subsequent access to trtr causes undefined behaviour, which might result in different behaviour on MS Windows than on Ubuntu. "Undefined behaviour is undefined."

The right way to allocate an array of int pointers would be `int **trtr = new int*[n]`. Note that I don't need a cast for that and that I used type `int*`.

The code you wanted to write might be:

```
#include <iostream>

int **lol(int *a, int n, int m)
{
    int **trtr = new int*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        trtr[i] = new int[m];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            trtr[i][j] = a[i * m + j];
        }
    }
    // for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    // {
    //         for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    //         {
    //                 *trtr[i][j] = a[i * m + j];
    //         }
    // }
    return trtr;
}

int main()
{
    int n, m;

    std::cin >> n >> m;

    int *a = new int[n * m];

    for (int i = 0; i < n * m; i++)
        a[i] = i;

    int **kekl = lol(a, n, m);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            std::cout << kekl[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

(I also removed the `using namespace std;`. You should try to avoid this.)

Comment: Thanks it works now. I needed triple pointers over there in order to assign it to the same memory space that has int a[]. so i just chaged it again to ***lol. But it works) mistake was here new int*[n]; just didn't know how to use it properly so i casted) now i know)